# LibVLCSharp UWP application not running on some networks

Tags: udp, libvlcsharp

I'm receiving a mp4 stream over UDP and want to show the video in real time in a UWP app. I'm using LibVLCSharp nuget to display the video stream. Trying to play the video directly using a UDP stream URI didn't work so I tried to pass the data received over UDP via a local http stream which worked successfully but throws the following exception,

> 'Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.'

while writing to the http stream as the data size(above 30KB) and frequency increased over some networks.

`LibVLC LibVLC = new LibVLC(enableDebugLogs: true, eventArgs.SwapChainOptions);`

`MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(LibVLC);`

`using (media = new Media(LibVLC, new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:5001/video/")))`

`{`

`MediaPlayer.Play(media);`

`}`

To keep the data size in check I started chunking the data I sent over UDP which increased the frequency of packets and thus crashes my app. To keep the frequency in check I added a timeout between 2 packets which leads to add latency to the video and thus the video always lags behind, running at a higher FPS than the original, trying to catch up but unable to do so.

At this point I'm out of ideas and unable to nail down specific reasons why this is working without any issues on some networks and crashes on the others. Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.

Update: Full logs for when the application is crashing

```
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.2_2.2.27902.3_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'D:\Windows App\vlcsharp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\entrypoint\vlcsharp.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'D:\Windows App\vlcsharp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'D:\Windows App\vlcsharp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'D:\Windows App\vlcsharp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Threading.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Collections.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Reflection.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Threading.Thread.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Private.Uri.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'D:\Windows App\vlcsharp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\LibVLCSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'D:\Windows App\vlcsharp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'D:\Windows App\vlcsharp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'D:\Windows App\vlcsharp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\SharpDX.Direct3D11.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'D:\Windows App\vlcsharp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\SharpDX.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'D:\Windows App\vlcsharp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\SharpDX.DXGI.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'D:\Windows App\vlcsharp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.ObjectModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Globalization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Net.HttpListener.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Net.Security.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Net.NameResolution.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Memory.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Net.Sockets.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Threading.Timer.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Net.ServicePoint.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Collections.Specialized.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Security.Claims.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Security.Principal.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

The thread 0x16a4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3db4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.HttpListenerException' in System.Net.HttpListener.dll

An exception of type 'System.Net.HttpListenerException' occurred in System.Net.HttpListener.dll but was not handled in user code
Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.NetCoreApp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vlcsharp.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.28529.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

Update 2: HttpListener Code

```
public void connectHttp()
        {
            HttpListener server = new HttpListener();
            server.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:5001/video/");

            server.Start();
            IAsyncResult result = server.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(Callback), server);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }

private void Callback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpListener server = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
            HttpListenerContext context = server.EndGetContext(result);
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
            
            response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
            response.SendChunked = true;

            while (!closing)
            {
                stream = response.OutputStream;
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
            server.Close();
        }
```

Update 3: LibVLC logs while streaming UDP directly

```
main Debug: VLC media player - 3.0.12.1 Vetinari
main Debug: keeping audio output
main Debug: Copyright © 1996-2020 the VideoLAN team
main Debug: revision 3.0.12.1-28-ge67c575d2c
main Debug: configured with ../configure  '--enable-winstore-app' '--disable-vlc' '--enable-lua' '--disable-vlm' '--disable-faad' '--enable-theora' '--disable-twolame' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-merge-ffmpeg' '--enable-dca' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-libass' '--disable-x264' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-live555' '--enable-shout' '--disable-goom' '--disable-caca' '--disable-qt' '--disable-skins2' '--enable-sse' '--enable-mmx' '--disable-libcddb' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-telx' '--enable-mad' '--disable-a52' '--enable-dsm' '--disable-smbclient' '--disable-vcd' '--disable-crystalhd' '--disable-dxva2' '--enable-flac' '--enable-jpeg' '--enable-vpx' '--enable-postproc' '--enable-gme' '--host=i686-w64-mingw32' 'host_alias=i686-w64-mingw32' 'CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc' 'LDFLAGS=-lnormaliz -lwinstorecompat  -lruntimeobject -lsynchronization -lvcruntime140_app -lucrt -lwindowsapp' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_WIN32_WINNT=0xA00 -DWINVER=0xA00 -DWINSTORECOMPAT -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_APP' 'CXX=i686-w64-mingw32-g++' 'PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/builds/videolan/vlc-winrt/libvlc/vlc/contrib/winrt-i686-ucrt/../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig'
main Debug: creating audio output
main Debug: looking for audio output module matching "winstore": 4 candidates
main Debug: using audio output module "winstore"
main Debug: Creating an input for 'udp://127.0.0.1:4502/'
main Debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
main Debug: creating access: udp://127.0.0.1:4502/
main Debug: looking for access module matching "udp": 24 candidates
main Debug: using default timeshift path
main Debug: net: connecting to [127.0.0.1]:4502 from []:1234
main Debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_block": 22 candidates
main Debug: using access module "udp"
cache_block Debug: Using block method for AStream*
cache_block Debug: starting pre-buffering
main Debug: `udp://127.0.0.1:4502/' gives access `udp' demux `any' path `127.0.0.1:4502/'
main Debug: no access_demux modules matched
main Debug: creating demux: access='udp' demux='any' location='127.0.0.1:4502/' file='\\127.0.0.1:4502\'
main Debug:  (path: \\127.0.0.1:4502\)
udp Debug: opening server=127.0.0.1:4502 local=:1234
main Debug: looking for access_demux module matching "udp": 6 candidates
The thread 0x30ac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1fe0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4030 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8fc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1808 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3830 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x34e4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1ab0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Did you manage to play the udp stream in the VLC desktop app? How did you create your http "proxy"?

Comment: @cube45 yes, I was able to play the udp stream in the VLC desktop app but the video was mainly a black screen with some blurred artifacts. I used HttpListener class for creating the http server and set the incoming udp data as the outputStream for the incoming http request from libVLC.

Comment: Please share full logs for the UDP issue in UWP, that should work. In the meantime, you could implement your own MediaInput subclass that reads from UDP (you'll likely need to implement your own buffer) instead of an HTTP implementation.

Comment: @cube45 I've edited my post to include the logs. Don't know if you were asking for anything in specific so I've added all the logs that I get while the application is crashing. I'll try looking into the MediaInput subclass.

Comment: `HttpListenerException` is coming from your code, not libvlcsharp. Share your code related to HttpListener

Comment: @mfkl I've added the httpListener code in my post above.

Comment: I meant the libvlc logs when playing the UDP stream directly : https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/blob/3.x/docs/troubleshooting.md

Comment: @cube45 I've added the logs for LibVLC for direct UDP stream.